# Is there a way to update a postgres column with varying[] data type?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table named Courses with a column named stringIds. This column contains an array of strings that represent different types. I want to update all rows in the table where the stringIds array contains the value "Tech" to "Introductory Tech".

e.g the column has a value `{Tech, Sciences, Biology}`, I'll like this to be updated to `{Introductory Tech, Sciences, Biology}`

I already have this query

```
UPDATE "Courses"
SET "stringIds" = (
  SELECT array_agg(
    CASE 
      WHEN elem = 'Tech' THEN 'Introductory Tech'::TEXT 
      ELSE elem 
    END
  )
  FROM unnest("stringIds") AS elem
)
WHERE array_to_json("stringIds")::jsonb @> '["Tech"]'::jsonb;
```

This query works to a large extent except that the Introductory Tech gets quoted in the update which I don't want. It gets updated to {"Introductory Tech", Sciences, Biology}. How can I remove the double quote?

Comment: Why do you use an array in the first place? A little extra normalization works best for relational databases like PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can I remove the double quote?*

You can't and you don't need to because the quotes aren't actually stored in the array. Those quotes are only used when *displaying* an array.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO)

> The array output routine will put double quotes around element values if they are empty strings, contain curly braces, delimiter characters, double quotes, backslashes, or white space, or match the word NULL

---

Unrelated to your question, but you can simplify your statement by using `array_replace()`

```
UPDATE "Courses"
  SET "stringIds" = array_replace("stringIds", 'Tech', 'Introductory Tech')
WHERE 'Tech' = any("stringIds")
```